# Começando com Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

Me interessei pelo xamarin e decidi testar a pouco tempo, o problema é que todos os tutoriais que eu vi tem a opção "portable", e no visual studio 2017 não tem, mesmo para android quanto para cross plataform (nao tenho mac).

Quando eu abro um "Blank App (Android)" ele abre diferente dos demais tutoriais, por exemplo:

O meu codigo:

```
    namespace App14
{
    [Activity(Label = "App14", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        }
    }
}

    namespace App14
{
    [Activity(Label = "App14", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            Button button = FindViewButtonId<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

            Button.Click +- delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++ ")}

        }
    }
}
```

E com isso eu fico perdido, nao achei nenhum tutorial atualizado e nem explicativo

Answer (score 0):

O caminho para criação de projetos PCL é um pouco diferente nas versões mais recentes do visual studio.
Vá em File > New Project > Cross-Platform > Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms).
Na estratégia de compartilhamento de código ou Code Sharing Strategy selecione ".NET Standard".
Feito isso o VS vai criar um projeto PCL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]